# prevent certain days from being chosen in input date?

Tags: jquery, html, date, input

Using input type="date" is there anyway i could prevent certain days from being chosen?

Looking for possibly a way to remove or a way to alert the user that the day they have chosen isn't available?

i.e. if day chosen is a monday, alert 'closed'?

I'm open to using jquery/javascript to throw the alert, i'm just tied to having to use the standard input type="date" for the input field.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$("input[type=date]").on("input", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Monday") {
         $(this).val("");
         alert("Closed");
    }
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle that illustrates my code: http://jsfiddle.net/cDG53/

Comment: Hi Valentin!

Thanks for the answer. that works perfectly if 'Monday' is entered, Ideally i'd like to do it by date, i.e. if the user chooses 14/07/14 - throw the alert, and so on for every monday.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You will have to find a way to know if the day is a Monday. The quickest way I think to do it is to calculate how many days have been spent since January 1st (ex 2nd february => 33) and also note which day was January the 1st and from then you can determine if the current day is a Monday